# Load partial view into div

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to load a partial view into a div from a calling view, however the
partial view loads into a new page.  There isn't much code to it and I've tried various
ways from other posts, but it still loads into a new page. So I think I might be missing something fundamental.

**Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Test()
{
    return PartialView("Test");
}
```

**View**

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Test", "Home", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "mydiv" }))
{    
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Save", "Test", "Home", new AjaxOptions{ });
}

<div id="mydiv">
    @Html.Partial("Test")
</div>
```

**PartialView**

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 23):

Couple of remarks about your code:

- `Ajax.*` helpers in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2 no longer use MS AJAX which has been deprecated in favor of jQuery, so your script inclusions are wrong. You need to include jquery
- You have an ajax form without a submit button and an ajax link inside this form. This makes no sense. Either use an ajax form or an ajax link.

So your code might look something among the lines:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Save", "Test", "Home", new AjaxOptions { 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "mydiv"
})

<div id="mydiv">
    @Html.Partial("Test")
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

Add this line to your page (master page or layout)

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

just after MicrosoftMvcAjax.js line.

Comment: I was struggling with this and this answer fixed my problem. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `<input type="submit" />` instead of `@Ajax.Actionlink(...)`

in MVC4 you can add bundle `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` just after `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` or add script reference in script section in page view as shown below:

```
@section scripts
    {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    }
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your partial needs to be within the ajax form

Comment: I'm checking Request.IsAjaxRequest() in the controller and it's coming back as false. The form markup is this. <form id="form0" method="post" data-ajax-update="#mydiv" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax="true" action="/Home/Test". Another thing is if I set the form to HttpMethod GET, it still does a post, not a get.