# Partial rendering in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to render a particular section/div click a particular link or button. Suppose link/button is in the `A.cshtml` page , and `b.cshtml` is a partial view that I want to load in `A.cshtml` page within a particular section/div. I tried `Ajax.ActionLink` but can't do. Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried ajaxactionlink but cant do

That's really not the way to ask a question here. *`Cant do`* is not a precise problem description. Next time when you ask a question on SO show what you have tried.

This being said, let me provide you with an example:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("click me", "SomeAction", new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId = "result"
})
<div id="result"></div>
```

and then you will have an action which will render this partial view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return PartialView("_NameOfYourPartial");
}
```

Finally make sure that you have referenced the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page which uses the HTML5 data-* attributes emitted by the `Ajax.ActionLink` helper to hijack the click event and send an AJAX request instead of the normal request:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller can return a partial view as action result:

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    var model = // your model
    var viewName = // your partial view name
    return PartialView(viewName, model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ajax.ActionLink` should do it, may be you missed somwthing.
Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557021/mvc-3-ajax-load-partial-view-into-div) it may give you the answer