# how to return view without refreshing a page in mvc3

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "HRBankInfo", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div align="center" class="display-label">
    @ViewBag.message
    <br /><input type="submit" value="Ok" />
    </div>

}
```

this is one of my partial view which appears on  operation success.it refreshes page and load index page i want to update page without reloading whole page.

Comment: You've tagged the question with ajax, so I guess you already know the answer :)

Comment: not yet.i have just started using ajax not really comfortable yet with ajax...wish u could help me out.

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557021/mvc-3-ajax-load-partial-view-into-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#buttonId').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('#divid').dialog('close');
});
</script>
```