# How to load records in MVC-view on demand

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application and using razor syntax.

In this application I am giving comment facility.

I have added a partial view, which loads the comment/Records from DB.

**currently, data get loaded as soon as that view get called, which I want to avoid it.**

**I wan to load the data only when user click on the Button, which is on that view.**

This is a code of the button.

```
<input type="button" value="Show" id="ShowId"  onclick="LoadData()"/>
```

And 
below Code should be executed when user click on the button.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div id="OwnerName">

         <span class="EmpName"> @Html.ActionLink(item.Owner.FullName, "Details", "EMployee", new { id = item.OwnerId }, new { @style = "color:#1A6690;" })</span>

           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentDateTime)

        </div>



        <p class="CommentP">
           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentText)
        </p>

        <br />


    }
```

How to do this ?

Comment: Please reply somebody...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to load comments from server after user click the button? The simplest way is use Jquery. Create action which will return `PartialViewResult` and then make ajax request with jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Here are concrete examples of loading data on demand:

- [JQuery AJAX with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41828/JQuery-AJAX-with-ASP-NET-MVC)
- [Load partial page in jquery and ASP.Net MVC](http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.ca/2012/05/load-partial-page-in-jquery-and-aspnet.html)

Follow their logic and adapt to your case.

**Update**

Ajax will do the work either (look into comments). *Thanks webdeveloper*

Hope this helps

Comment: I dont think I want this...do I need to write Javascript for this ?

Comment: Yes we do, cannot do without. Look for any load on demand in MVC topic, all them are using jquery. But its not hard at all, just look what and how they do and do the same.

Comment: He could use alternative way with ajax helpers: [MVC 3 - Ajax load partial view into div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557021/mvc-3-ajax-load-partial-view-into-div)

Comment: True. What I meant to say was that you cannot do purely within ASP.NET MVC. Have to employ something else (jquery, ajax, whatever will do the work). Because I had this dilemma myself when learning these things - wanted to do everything within technology boundaries, but with time realized that adjacent technologies compliment this framework and make your life much easier, rather than harder. UPdated answer with Ajax. Thanks webdeveloper.